# Child routes with tabs / router outlets are not working. "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment"

Tags: angular, nativescript

When I try the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "", component: RegisteredLayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo:
          "/(topicsTab:topicsPage//newsTab:newsPage//homeTab:homePage//askTab:askPage//moreTab:morePage)",
        pathMatch: "full"
      },
      { path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent, outlet: "homeTab" },...

{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

I get "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment"

Am I doing something wrong?  The page that contains the router outlets looks like:

```
<BottomNavigation selectedIndex="2">
    <TabStrip backgroundColor="white">
        <TabStripItem>
            <Label text="Topics" class="icon__color"></Label>
            <Image src="~/assets/round_people_black_18dp.png" class="fas t-36 icon__color"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem class="special">
            <Label text="News" class="icon__color"></Label>
            <Image src="~/assets/round_local_library_black_18dp.png" class="fas t-36 icon__color"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem class="special">
            <Label text="Home" class="icon__color"></Label>
            <Image src="~/assets/round_home_black_18dp.png" class="fas t-36 icon__color"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem class="special">
            <Label text="Ask?" class="icon__color"></Label>
            <Image src="~/assets/round_contact_support_black_18dp.png" class="fas t-36 "></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem class="special">
            <Label text="More" class="icon__color"></Label>
            <Image src="~/assets/round_more_horiz_black_18dp.png" class="fas t-36 icon__color"></Image>
        </TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>
    <!-- The number of TabContentItem components should corespond to the number of TabStripItem components -->
    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="topicsTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="newsTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="homeTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="askTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="moreTab"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>
</BottomNavigation>
```

Can someone let me know what is the proper way to redirect?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this upon launch? BottomNavigation is the root view for your app?

Comment: The root is a regular <page-router-outlet ></page-router-outlet>. Than I route dependent it the authguard come back as true.   {
    path: "", component: UnregisteredLayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: "loginPage1", component: LoginPage1Component },
   
    ]
  },...    path: "", component: RegisteredLayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [...      Let me know if need more info. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you setup a Playground?

Comment: Hi Manoj. Here is the playgound.  https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=u1cDaZ  . Thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to do this in code behind: { path: "", redirectTo: "/(topicsTab:topicsPage//newsTab:newsPage//homeTab:homePage//askTab:askPage//moreTab:morePage)", pathMatch: 'full' },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it :-)  What really helped me get the right route was enabling tracing like so:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
```

})

One I could see the trace, I realized that I did not have the registeredRoute in the path of my redirect!

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'registeredRoute', pathMatch: 'full' },
{
    path: "registeredRoute", component: RegisteredLayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
        { path: "", component: HomeComponent, outlet: "homeTab" },
        { path: "homePage", component: HomeComponent, outlet: "homeTab" },
        { path: "topicsPage", component: TopicsComponent, outlet: "topicsTab" },
        { path: "newsPage", component: NewsComponent, outlet: "newsTab" },
        { path: "askPage", component: AskComponent, outlet: "askTab" },
        { path: "morePage", component: MoreComponent, outlet: "moreTab" }
    ]
},
{
    path: "", component: UnregisteredLayoutComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'loginPage', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: "loginPage", component: LoginComponent }

    ]
    ,
},
 { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

];

Answer (score 1):

Upon login you were trying to navigate relatively, but you are suppose to load a different module (as per your router setup, login is under `unRegisteredRoute` and tabview is under `registeredRoute`).

```
this.router.navigate(["/registeredRoute", { outlets: { topicsTab: ['topicsPage'], newsTab: ['newsPage'], homeTab: ['homePage'], askTab: ['askPage'], moreTab: ['morePage'] } }]);
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=u1cDaZ&v=3)